# Тройной sql запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Столкнулся с проблемой вложенности запроса.
Имеются три таблицы:

1. `actors (id, name)` - таблица актеров с именами.
2. `actors_video (id, id_actor, id_video)` - таблица с данными о участии актера в фильме.
3. `video (id, name)` - таблица с фильмами.

таблицы `actors` и `actors_video` - залиты полностью, а в таблицу `video` постепенно публикуются материалы.

У меня имеется страница актеров, где выводятся все актеры (с таблицы `actors`). Но есть нюанс, когда актер выводится, а фильмов у него нет.
Поэтому вопрос, как сделать запрос когда выводятся все актеры, у которых есть минимум 5 фильмов?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае между таблицами есть связи по внешним ключам и не составляет труда их сджойнить без подзапросов вовсе. И отсортировать результат

```
select  act.id
from actors act
join actors_video a_vid on vid.id_actor = act.id
join video vid on vid.id = a_vid.id_video
group by act.id
having count(vid.id) >= 5;
```

Comment: select  act.id
from actors act
join actors_video a_vid on a_vid.id_actor = act.id
join video vid on vid.id = a_vid.id_video
group by act.id
having count(vid.id) >= 5;

Я немного изменил ваш код, т.к. в таблице video нет id_actor.

Но теперь выдает один результат, хотя должно быть много.

Comment: Я учел это, связ таблиц actors и video идет через actors_video

Answer (score 0):

знакомы ли вы с группировкой `GROUP BY` фильтрацией групп `HAVING` и функциями а-ля `COUNT` ?

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM actors AS a
INNER JOIN actors_video as av ON (av.id_actor = a.id) 
GROUP by a.id, a.name
HAVING count(av.id_video) >= 5
```